# Indexing not working properly in MS-SQL table with 50+ Million records on datetime2 property

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have SQL tables with following columns and data type. Records between Table1 and Table2 are one to one mapped by UniqueId2. But, since they are inserted by 2 different independent processes at different times, there is no foreign key constraints between two tables (no dependency on each other table).

When we try to query data using below query, it is taking few minutes to retrieve data between 2 dates (sometimes 15-20 mins) even though the duration between 2 dates is a day or two.

We have noticed that sometimes index is being applied by optimizer and sometimes it is being ignored completely.

Is there anyway we can retrieve data quickly in seconds or with better performance?

**Query**:

```
SELECT tab1.String4, tab1.UniqueId3, tab1.Table1Id, tab1.UniqueId4, tab1.UniqueId1, tab1.String3, tab1.String1, tab1.String2, tab1.String5, tab1.DateTime1, tab2.DateTime8, tab2.Table2Id, tab2.int1, tab1.DateTime2, tab1.DateTime3
FROM Table1 tab1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 tab2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON tab1.UniqueId2 = tab2.UniqueId2
WHERE 1=1
AND tab1.DateTime1 BETWEEN '{date1}' AND '{date2}'
AND tab1.UniqueId3 = '{id3}'
AND tab1.String3 = '{str3}'
AND tab1.String4 = '{str1}'
AND tab1.UniqueId2 = '{id2}'
ORDER BY tab1.DateTime2 OFFSET {intValue} ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
```

**Tables and Indexes:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Table1Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [UniqueId1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UniqueId2] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UniqueId3] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UniqueId4] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [String1] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [String2] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [String3] [varchar] (36) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [String4] [varchar] (36) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [String5] [varchar] (15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [String6] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [String7] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [DateTime1] [datetime2] (2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [DateTime2] [datetime2] (2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [DateTime3] [datetime2] (2) NOT NULL,
    [Int1] [int] NULL
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Table1Id])
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DateTime1Index] ON [dbo].[Table1] ([DateTime1])
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UniqueId2Index] ON [dbo].[Table1] ([UniqueId2])
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [Table2Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
    [UniqueId1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UniqueId2] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [DateTime6] [datetime2] (2) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime7] [datetime2] (2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [DateTime8] [datetime2] (2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [Int1] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Table2Id])
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UniqueId2Index] ON [dbo].[Table2] ([UniqueId2])
GO
```

Comment: Can you try instead using `BETWEEN` to use `>=` and `<`?

Comment: The indexes you show us aren't going to be particularly useful when you have multiple other columns in the `WHERE` and `SELECT`; none of the indexes are covering indexes. At "best" this means that the data engine will choose to do a lookup followed by key lookup, followed by a scan of that data, but a scan of the whole tables is very likely going to be the "easier" and "simpler" choice for it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your queries can use different filtering criteria in combination of the date filter. If so, it's hard to create an index which will optimize all queries. For example, in your sample query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table1 tab1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 tab2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON tab1.UniqueId2 = tab2.UniqueId2
WHERE 1=1
AND tab1.DateTime1 BETWEEN '{date1}' AND '{date2}'
AND tab1.UniqueId3 = '{id3}'
AND tab1.String3 = '{str3}'
AND tab1.String4 = '{str1}'
AND tab1.UniqueId2 = '{id2}'
...
```

We are filtering by DateTime1, UniqueId3, String3, String4, UniqueId2 and we can create index with them, but if you add new column, the index might not be used.

If your date time filter is the filter which is reducing the rows most, I will suggest to create index on the `DateTime1` and the to filter the rows in advance.

```
CREATE #FilteredRowsByDate TABLE
(
    Table1Id uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT INTO #FilteredRowsByDate (Table1Id)
SELECT Table1Id
FROM  [dbo].[Table1]
WHERE DateTime1 BETWEEN '{date1}' AND '{date2}'

SELECT tab1.String4, tab1.UniqueId3, tab1.Table1Id, tab1.UniqueId4, tab1.UniqueId1, tab1.String3, tab1.String1, tab1.String2, tab1.String5, tab1.DateTime1, tab2.DateTime8, tab2.Table2Id, tab2.int1, tab1.DateTime2, tab1.DateTime3
FROM #FilteredRowsByDate F
INNER JOIN Table1 tab1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON F.Table1Id = Tb1.Table1Id
INNER JOIN Table2 tab2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON tab1.UniqueId2 = tab2.UniqueId2
WHERE 1=1
AND tab1.DateTime1 BETWEEN '{date1}' AND '{date2}'
AND tab1.UniqueId3 = '{id3}'
AND tab1.String3 = '{str3}'
AND tab1.String4 = '{str1}'
AND tab1.UniqueId2 = '{id2}'
ORDER BY tab1.DateTime2 OFFSET {intValue} ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: we do already have an index on dateTime1 of table1. Since, this is not a stored procedure and query being invoked by an app, is there a way we can split this query in to 2 parts so that app can invoke both the queries to improve performance of overall result?